# How to use SED to replace underscores with hyphens in URLs?

Tags: sed

Hi this looks like a common problem but I can't find a solution via googling or SO.  Within several HTML files kept in a local directory I need to change URLs from http://www.myblog.com from using underscores in the ending part of the URL to using hyphens instead.  (Any other URLs need to remain unchanged.)  I use Ubuntu Linux, I think SED will work for me here but can use other tools instead if helpful.

So if an HTML file includes:

```
<a href="http://www.myblog.com/my_blog_article">...</a>
```

I need to switch it to:

```
<a href="http://www.myblog.com/my-blog-article">...</a>
```

The URLs in question will appear only within HTML anchor tags.  Also, the underscore-to-hyphen part will occur only on the ending part (i.e., after the last "/" in the URL string.)  I can't just do a global search-and-replace (s/_/-/g) because there are potentially URLs to other sites and other underscores not related to URLs that I wouldn't want to alter.

Comment: Since `sed`s replacements are based on regular expressions (regexes), searching for help with those may get you better results than looking specifically for `sed` commands - although knowing you're using `sed` will help you watch out for its specific regex features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk`

```
awk -F\" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/http/) {n=split($i,a,"/");gsub(/_/,"-",a[n]);for (j=1;j<=n;j++) {s=s (s?"/":"") a[j];$i=s}}print $0}' OFS=\" file
<a href="http://www.myblog.com/my-blog-article">data with_underscore</a>
```

This will only replace `_` if its in the file path of the `url`

A more readable version:

```
awk -F\" '
    {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if ($i~/http/) {
            n=split($i,a,"/")
            gsub(/_/,"-",a[n])
            for (j=1;j<=n;j++) {
                s=s (s?"/":"") a[j]
                $i=s}
            }
        print $0
    }' OFS=\" file
```

Comment: That sounds a little too imprecise: what about a line containing a URL and a separate word with an underscore in?

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing this now.  Question:  If I have 15 html files in a folder "temp", is there a nice way to feed all 15 to this awk command and have it create 15 output files (whether different name or overwrite, I don't care) with the results?

Comment: You make use `while loop` in a `bash` program to loop trough a give list of files.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;/<a href="http:\/\/www.myblog.com\/[^"]*_[^"]*"/{s//\n&\n/;h;y/_/-/;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/;ba}' file
```

If a line contains the URL as shown in the question, surround the URL by markers (newlines in this case), copy the line and then translate the '_''s to '-''s. Append the original line and reassemble using the markers as guides. Repeat the process until all URL's are processed.